# Add a Value other than 1 to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet in which there are yes and no question, I want to add a specific value to each yes and no answer. How can I do that? I added =COUNTIFS(J2,"yes") but this gives me a value of 1 for Yes and 0 for No.

Comment: Your `COUNTIFS` statement is looking only at one cell so will only give you 0 or 1. If you want different numbers, then use an `IF` statement. Like `IF(J2="yes",5,-3)`.

Answer (score 0):

With values in column **J**.  Say we want *3* for every *yes* and *2* for every *no*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(J2:J20="yes"))*3+SUMPRODUCT(--(J2:J20="no"))*2
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C10,"YES")+COUNTIF(C1:C10,"NO")
```

[image]